# C - make negative value positive and use it outside a function

Tags: c, if-statement

I have the following code that makes `difference` negative if it's sum is below 0 but it doesn't update the value of `difference` properly. why?

```
    // if difference is negative, it is multiplied by -1
    if (difference < 0) {
        difference * -1;
    }
```

What am I doing wrong here?

FIX

```
if (difference < 0) {
        difference = difference * -1;
    }
```

Comment: Why do you have both `seconds1()` and `seconds2()` when they do exactly the same job?  One of the two is sufficient.  In `wrongSeconds()`, `wrongMinutes()` and `wrongHours()`, you have an unused local variable `int i;`.  If your compiler doesn't warn you about unused variables, you aren't setting its fussiness level high enough, or you need a better compiler.

Comment: You might also notice that if you enter, for sake of example, 12 hours and 36 minutes and then 99 seconds, on re-entry, you can enter 256 hours, 345 minutes and 23 seconds and your validation doesn't spot that re-entered hours and minutes are completely bogus. You ought, surely, to be able to encapsulate the code for entering one time into a function.  Ideally, you'd pass that a control argument like `"first"` or `"second"` so that you can have one function for both inputs. And you should check that `scanf()` is successful — if the user types `a` instead of `12`, the code will be very unhappy.

Comment: The question is inconsistent. From it's introducing text one understands you want to do: Time1 -Time2. Whereas the code you show does it the other way round.

Answer (score 4):

you need to change it like `difference = difference * -1;`

Answer (score 3):

Just to answer your exact question:

The below line is incorrect.

```
if (difference < 0) {
        difference * -1;
    }
```

It should be

```
if (difference < 0) {
        difference = difference * -1;
    }
```

Comment: Or `difference *= -1;` or `difference = -difference;` or `difference = abs(difference);` or …

Answer (score 1):

When you do this:

```
difference * -1;
```

You multiply the value of `difference` by -1, but since you don't assign it to anything or otherwise use this value in an expression the result is being thrown away.

Assign the result back to `difference`:

```
difference = difference * -1;
```

Alternately, you can first check which one is larger, then subtract the smaller from the larger:

```
int difference = (totalTimeTwo > totalTime) ? totalTimeTwo - totalTime :
                                              totalTime - totalTimeTwo;
```